# JPA hibernate: create undeletable entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to make a persisted entity undeletable in JPA hibernate via annotation?

I'm thinking in terms of audit records that wouldn't want to be deleted by accident, ie rather than enforcing it as a verbal cavaet. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't give the user application user 'delete' privileges on the audit table?

Comment: I can give that a try, thanks!